# Haskell function causing stack overflow

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

I'm relatively new to Haskell and rather inexperienced with programming in general.
A function is causing a stack overflow on certain inputs and I'm not sure why.

Function in question:

```
digitSum :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
digitSum _ 1 = 1
digitSum base x = (x `mod` base) + digitSum base (x `div`base)
```

On some inputs (e.g. 10 15, 11 121, 16 19, 3 1234) it works while on others (10 456 for example) it breaks
Could someone explain this to me, so that I can avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack overflow in a functional language often means: unbounded recursion. And, indeed, it is what happens here, for a lot of inputs: take for instance `digitSum 2 0`. It doesn't match the first pattern match, so it goes for the second case, with `base=2` and `x=0`. `` x `mod` base = 1 `` and `` x `div` base = 0 ``. It then makes a recursive call to `digitSum 2 0`. Then forever.

This is because your base case is wrong: it should be `digitSum _ 0 = 0` instead, because if you keep integer dividing `x` by `base`, if `base` is not `1`, you'll always end up with `0`.

Answer (score 3):

[BlackBeans has the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74179508/15261315), but as an addendum, it's possible to see a stack overflow not only on unbounded recursion, but also on simply *too much* recursion. Fortunately this is easy to address by writing your functions in a tail-recursive manner. If you do this, your Haskell compiler can run the function in constant stack space.

A common way to accomplish this is by adding an accumulator parameter, and this is often hidden from the user of the function with a local function.

```
digitSum :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
digitSum = digitSum' 0
  where
    digitSum' acc _    0 = acc
    digitSum' acc base x = digitSum (acc + x `mod` base) base (x `div` base)
```

If you write your functions in a tail-recursive style *and* have unbounded recursion, do not expect to see a stack overflow, but do expect to see the program simply hang as the recursion is not terminating.